# How to load resource file in Java?

Tags: java, configuration

I have the following source structure:

```
src
    resources
        config.properties
        data.txt
```

I copy these files into my jar, without flattening. So the jar contains `resources/config.properties` and `resources/data.txt`

The config.properties works fine while running locally (Eclipse: Run as | Run Configurations) and executing the jar.

```
private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH = "resources/config.properties";
resourceInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH);
configurationProperties.load(resourceInputStream);
```

The data.txt file works locally (Eclipse: Run as | Run Configurations) but is not found when executing jar. I do need the File object created, as I then pass it to a third party library.

```
private static final String DATA_FILE_PATH = "resources/data.txt";
URL resourceUrl = classLoader.getResource(DATA_FILE_PATH);
File file = resourceUrl == null ? null : new File(resourceUrl.getPath());
```

when executing the jar, `file` is null.

**Is it an execution issue?**

I'm calling the jar from Jenkins `jar /build/myapp.jar` . Should I be setting class path for this execution? I mean the `-cp` switch..?

**Open to other load options**

As mentioned above, the `config.properties` loads fine. I don't need my `data.txt` to load with `getResource`. I'm open to other methods. As long as I can get a `File` from it.

Comment: Start with a slash e.g. "/resources/data.txt"

Comment: I tried that but that fails local run. Even if this would make the jar work, I still need it to work locally.

Comment: We'll need more info about a "local run" because it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made some assumptions. Let me update the question with what I mean by 'local run'.

Comment: Finding a resource happens relative to the classpath. If running locally, the target directory wherein the package `resources` lives should be in the classpath.

Comment: Locally (Eclipse), this would be the /bin folder. /bin contains /resources with its contents exactly as the jar does. And locally it works. I'm not too fussy with how you advise to set it up, I just need it to work in Eclipse and in the executable jar.

Comment: OK so now it works as a local run?  So what's the problem, when it's in a Jar file?

Comment: Yes, without the leading slash it works locally but not in the executable jar. If I add the leading slash, it stops working locally.

Comment: But with the leading slash it works in the Jar?  If not, can you dump the raw contents of the Jar to verify the path names in the Jar?

Comment: Honestly I'm leaning towards "Eclipse has a bug."  NetBeans also periodically has the same issue, where it can't read resources correctly, until they fix it in the next update.  All I want to do is verify that you have the correct paths set up.  If you do, then it's time to ask the Eclipse folks when they'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Java resources, you have to start the resource name with a slash to make it absolute or relative to the top of your Jar hierarchy.

Resource names that do not start with a slash are relative to the current location (package name/directory) of the class that loads them.

Comment: Mark, are you sure you have `src/resources` structure? I'm guessing but you might have resource files directly under the project folder.

Comment: src is part of Java's standard directory structure, which NetBeans uses by default.  src is never included in the path names/class path; it's always one level above where your binaries are actually located.

Comment: But resources are copied to the target directory (same as compile target) without flattening. I mentioned this in my question. So there's no need to discuss src.